# How to prevent Task Scheduler errors/fails

Tags: scheduled-task, batch, task-scheduler

There seems to be lots of myths and bugs
upon research not many useful items were returned or maybe outdated

1. "Run whether logged on or not", according to many posts/results saying this function is bugged and batch files are not get kicked off properly.

> Seems like as long as "Program/Script" and "Start in" are configure properly the problem shouldn't happen?

2. How to get notified when

   - Task not fire properly

     > Seems like the only way is run another task with trigger event, but isn't there a possibility that that notification task wouldn't fire properly?
   - Batch file failed

     > Seems like the only was is to add additional error check for every single batch file?

If there is any other tips/trick you would like to share please do shout out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: the point forms are the questions..but I'm not sure if what I researched are valid as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start (or the error) will be logged in the window events log. So you don't need to add a event trigger to survey the starting state of the first task.

Now, the main problem of the task scheduler is when your task starts normally but the executed script has an error or generate a problem. In this case, the scheduler has done his job to start the task, the result of the script is not its problem. You must add in your script an error management.

For logging problems in yours scripts, you can write the output in a file. For information, the event (id 201) give the return code of the executed script by the scheduler.

**EDIT 1 :**

The simpliest in my opinion is to include in yours scripts the send of mail which log the result of your script.

The best is the installation of a supervision system which will survey the execution of the task and the results of the script

Comment: I meant trigger event to send notification email to admin. So Admin can attend to it right away

Comment: ... see edit 1...